# Is my multithreaded form code correct?

Tags: c#, multithreading, form

The basic idea is this:

There are two buttons: a `DoWork` button and a `Cancel` button.

The `DoWork` button should launch a thread to do some work, unless that thread was already launched and not canceled.

The `Cancel` button should cancel the worker thread, if it's running.

Please ignore the fact that it calls `Thread.Abort()` for the moment, that is a separate issue that I will address later.

Also, how does one generally show the correctness of one's own multithreaded code?  It seems much more difficult to debug.

Here's the code:

```
    private Thread m_WorkingThread;
    private bool m_finishedWorking;

    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // initialize all the form controls.
        m_WorkingThread = null;
        m_finishedWorking = false;
    }

    private void bDoWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (m_WorkingThread != null)
            if(m_WorkingThread.IsAlive  || m_finishedWorking)
                return;

        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(DoWork);
        Thread t = new Thread(ts);
        t.Start();
        m_WorkingThread = t;

    }
    private void bCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbortThread(m_WorkingThread);
        m_finishedWorking = false;
    }
    private void AbortThread(Thread t)
    {
        if (t != null)
            if (t.IsAlive)
                t.Abort();
    }
    private void DoWork()
    {
        // do some work here, maybe using Invokes / BeginInvokes to update any controls.

        m_finishedWorking = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)? It might save you some trouble.

However, it does use ThreadPool and you are better to create your own threads if you have any of the following [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx):

- You require a foreground thread.
- You require a thread to have a particular priority.
- You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from starting.
- You need to place threads into a single-threaded apartment. All ThreadPool threads are in the multithreaded apartment.
- You need to have a stable identity associated with the thread, or to dedicate a thread to a task.

I add my comment to the answer of "Peter K." here as it seemed to please you.

> Mutex is a bit overkill as it works
>   across multiple processes. One should
>   use locks (i.e. Monitor) when there is
>   no need to synchronize across
>   processes. Anyway, I don't see here
>   any need for the locks assuming that
>   the bDoWork_Click() is always called
>   from the UI thread. It only creates a
>   new thread if the existing thread is
>   not alive. However, the resources used
>   by DoWork() must be protected with
>   locks if they are shared with other
>   threads.

Comment: I have, but I am not too familiar with it except that it uses the threadpool.  Ultimately I need to have threads that start when somebody clicks a button, and pause the other threads until that "top" thread finishes.  Consequently there can be many running threads (like if the user keeps clicking various things) and I hear the threadpool is not so good for such things (many / long-running threads.)  In general though you might be right, I really don't know anything about them.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by pausing the other threads. I hope that you are not going to suspend any background threads because you should not do that.

Comment: Yeah, by pausing I don't mean in the traditional sense.  Each thread calls something like while(paused[threadId]) Thread.Sleep(someAmount), before doing any substantial work.  Or is that still a bad approach?

Comment: You could also use ManualResetEventSlim instance to control the state for each thread. Instead of while loop you would just call paused[threadId].Wait() and the thread will stay there paused until the corresponding ManualResetEventSlim instance is Set(). With Reset() you can request a pause again and the thread will pause when it reaches the Wait(). It should do what you want. Your current implementation may not work correctly unless there is a memory barrier that forces the value of paused[threadId] to be read from the memory and not from the cache.

Comment: Great.  I'll try to use those instead of a list of bools, unless you know how to get a list of volatile bools. :-P  (Although I guess I could have a list of locks associated w/ each bool.)  And the lists themselves would need to have locks associated w/ them.  yay multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use shared variables is generally a **Bad Thing(TM)**.  The usual way to do cross-thread locking / resource checking is via a mutex.

Something like this, though I haven't compiled or checked it:

```
private Thread m_WorkingThread;
private static Mutex m_FinishedWorking  = new Mutex(); 

public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // initialize all the form controls.
    m_WorkingThread = null;
}

private void bDoWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (m_WorkingThread != null)
        if(m_WorkingThread.IsAlive)
            return;

    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(DoWork);
    Thread t = new Thread(ts);
    t.Start();
    m_WorkingThread = t;

}
private void bCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AbortThread(m_WorkingThread);
}
private void AbortThread(Thread t)
{
    if (t != null)
        if (t.IsAlive)
            t.Abort();
}
private void DoWork()
{
    m_FinishedWorking.WaitOne();
    // do some work here, maybe using Invokes / BeginInvokes to update any controls.

    // Must be called if the thread is aborted.
    m_FinishedWorking.ReleaseMutex();        
}
```

Comment: Mutex is a bit overkill as it works across multiple processes. One should use locks (i.e. Monitor) when there is no need to synchronize across processes. Anyway, I don't see here any need for the locks assuming that the bDoWork_Click() is always called from the UI thread. It only creates a new thread if the existing thread is not alive. However, the resources used by DoWork() must be protected with locks if they are shared with other threads.

Comment: @mgronber: I would like to accept your comment. :-P

Answer (score 1):

I could not find something wrong in your code.

But I would suggest, of course depending on your Framework Version, to use Tasks instead of Threads - System.Threading.Tasks offers you a very good API.

Here a quick example, maybe not bulletproof - but I think you will get the idea:

```
private Task task;
private CancellationTokenSource tokensource;
private CancellationToken token;    

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  tokensource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  token = tokensource.Token;
  this.Cancel.Enabled = false;
}

private void DoWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (task != null && !task.IsCompleted) return;

  this.DoWork.Enabled = false;
  this.Cancel.Enabled = true;
  task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWorkAction(), token)
    .ContinueWith(_ => { this.DoWork.Enabled = true; this.Cancel.Enabled = false; }, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  tokensource.Cancel();
}

private void DoWorkAction() {
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into them.  Unfortunately I think it uses ThreadPool, which I am hoping to avoid.